# Linux SSL TCP file redirection?

Tags: linux, bash, ssl

In Linux it is possible to do such thing :

```
ps aux > /dev/tcp/1.1.1.1/1234
```

And listening on the other side with ncat or nc.

But is there a way to do it over SSL encryption ?

Preferably with X509 common/alt name authentication.

Thank you very much !

Comment: `man 1 socat`, seek `OPENSSL`. I have never done it, therefore just a comment.

Comment: To add to the previous comment: you can't do this exactly the way you do with the "virtual" file but you can use a program like the suggested `socat` or `openssl s_client` or similar which can read from stdin and write to a remote system by using SSL.